# Hive Command Line - problems with backticks in column name

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

When I try creating a table using beeline / hive command line for the following DDL :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE schema.table
(
`Week` string,
`Orders` string,
`Units` string
)
COMMENT 'This table was auto generated'
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ',',
   'quoteChar' = '\"',
   'escapeChar' = '\\'
   )
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '/data/qa/ingest_id=1543338670'
 TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

I get the following error

```
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 3:0 character '▒' not supported here
line 3:1 character '▒' not supported here
line 3:2 character '▒' not supported here (state=42000,code=40000)
```

Has anyone faced this issue before? This DDL executes without issues on a GUI client.

Comment: are you doing copy paste, if so could you try to re-type ` character

Comment: Found the issue - it was related to unicode characters. I removed them and it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related UTF 8 encoding. Removed unicode characters from the shell.

```
tr -d '\200-\277' | tr -d '\300-\377'
```